# Wikidata query - how to add year to city's population?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I would like to get the year of population count for each city.

Do tou know how to add it correctly? Currently I got empty results.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityLabel ?population ?gps ?data WHERE {
?city (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515;
wdt:P1082 ?population;
wdt:P625 ?gps.
OPTIONAL { ?population wdt:P585 ?date. } # here I have a problem
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population) LIMIT 100
```

PS. just paste it here: https://query.wikidata.org/

Answer (score 1):

- First problem: you are selecting `?data` but the actual variable is `?date`.
- Second problem: `?population` is the *object* of your statement, but [qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers) refer to a whole statement, not just its object.

For referring to the statement, you'll have to use `p:P1082` instead of `wdt:P1082`.

You can obtain what you want with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityLabel ?population ?gps ?date WHERE {
  ?city
    wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
    wdt:P625 ?gps.
  ?city p:P1082 ?populationStatement .
  ?populationStatement ps:P1082 ?population .
  OPTIONAL { ?populationStatement pq:P585 ?date. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 10
```

I set `LIMIT 10` because this is a pretty heavy query and sometimes it reaches timeout.

To deepen the topic, I'd suggest you to read [Wikidata:SPARQL tutorial§Qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial#Qualifiers).